# Printing the value of a structure pointer variable member

Tags: c, linux, pointers, structure

Why am I getting a "segmentation fault" error when I run this after compiling?

[image]

//CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){

    struct name{
        char first[20];
        char last[20];
    } *person;

    strcpy(person->first, "jordan");
    strcpy(person->last, "davis");

    printf("firstname: %s\n", person->first);
    printf("lastname: %s\n", person->last);
}
```

Comment: What are you using to compile it? What is throwing the error? The compiler, or the compiled program?

Comment: @ElmerCat Thats the output when I run the program after it's compiled.

Comment: @JordanDavis: in future, describe things more accurately.  If you got a segmentation fault while compiling, it would be the compiler crashing, which might be quite exciting and would probably be a bug unless there were very unusual extenuating circumstances — compilers don't crash.  OTOH, users' programs do crash quite routinely when they're run.  I've updated the question so it reflects your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `person` pointer has not been initialized. So there is no valid `struct name` object when you dereference the pointer.

Either use malloc:

```
person = malloc(sizeof *person);
```

or just declare an object of type `struct name` instead of `struct name *` (and then don't forget to access your structure members with `.` operator instead of `->`).

Comment: Is it not being initializing it at the end of the `struct name` statement?

Comment: @Jordan `person` pointer was never initialized or assigned, its value is unspecified.

Comment: If it's not initialized... then how am I referencing it in my `strcpy()` statements...

Comment: The end of the `struct name` statement `} *person;` should be declaring and assigning the pointer variable to the `name` - structure.... here is a ref --> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: @JordanDavis Not at all, you are declaring `person` as an object of type `struct name *` (that is a pointer to `struct name`). `person` object was never initialized.

Comment: Are you referring to "object" as a structure "member"?

Comment: I'm referring to the `person` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89202/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-ouah).